# Executing a batch file from local server to multiple remote servers using powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I would like execute the below batch file (using `PowerShell`) from local server which will get results from multiple remote servers and I would like to get those results in `C:\temp folder`.

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Program Files\Tivoli\TSM\baclient"
dsmc.exe q mgmtclass > C:\temp\TSMmgmtclass.txt
```

After that, would like to get those output results using `PowerShell` script as mentioned below.

```
Get-Content -Path 'C:\Program Files\tivoli\tsm\baclient\dsmerror.log' | select-object -last 15
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is probably using invoke-command, and eliminating the .bat file completely.  it would look something like this

```
$scriptBlock = {
  & "C:\Program Files\Tivoli\TSM\baclient\dsmc.exe" q mgmtclass
  return $return
}

invoke-command -computername $computernames -scriptblock $scriptBlock | out-file $logfile
```

In this case $computernames would be an array holding the name of each computer you want to run the command against and $logfile is just the path you want the contents output to.

Comment: I tried that & I am getting error mentioned below -

Comment: The term 'C:\Program Files\Tivoli\TSM\baclient\dsmc.exe q mgmtclass' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,  verify that the path is correct and try again.

    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Program File...exe q mgmtclass:String) [], CommandNotFoundException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

    + PSComputerName        : ServerName1

Comment: My apologies, mis-formatted the .exe call, it should look like this

    `& "C:\Program Files\Tivoli\TSM\baclient\dsmc.exe" q mgmtclass`

Comment: @RyanBemrose Thank you, I have edited my answer accordingly